# Returning default members when Enum member does not exist

Tags: python, enums

I have an Enum where I would like a default member to be returned when a member does not exist inside of it. For example:

```
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    A = 12
    B = 24
    CUSTOM = 1


print(MyEnum.UNKNOWN) # Should print MyEnum.CUSTOM
```

I know I can use a metaclass like so:

```
class MyMeta(enum.EnumMeta):
    def __getitem__(cls, name):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(name)
        except KeyError as error:
            return cls.CUSTOM

class MyEnum(enum.Enum,metaclass=MyMeta):
    ...
```

But that appears to only work if I access the Enum using `MyEnum['UNKNOWN']`. Is there a way that covers both methods of accessing members of an enum when the member doesn't exist?

Comment: So, looking at the implementation of  [`EnumMeta.__getattr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9369942054fe3fe389f4f4ff808d33c5d7945052/Lib/enum.py#L423) it uses the private attribute directly, so one simple fix is to *also* override `__getattribute__` doing essentially the same thing except catch an `AttributeError`

Comment: Also, assuming this is a typo, but `class MyEnum(enum.enumMeta,metaclass=MyMeta):` should be `class MyEnum(enum.Enum, metaclass=MyMeta):`

Comment: Currently, a `_missing_` method exists to do what you are asking when a value is not available -- so `MyEnum(7)` would return `MyEnum.UNKNOWN`.  The reason that doesn't work with attribute access is because if typing out `MyEnum.WHATEVER` in source code, the programmer should know what the actual members are.  What is your use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a definition for `__getattr__` to the metaclass:

```py
class MyMeta(enum.EnumMeta):
    def __getitem__(cls, name):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(name)
        except KeyError as error:
            return cls.CUSTOM
    
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        try:
            return super().__getattr__(name)
        except AttributeError as error:
            return cls.CUSTOM
```

Then, your code will output:

```py
MyEnum.CUSTOM
```